# How to create table with a name and fields that we enter?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a stored procedure to create table with name and fields that we enter in a form.

Comment: Please provide a little more info. What SQL dialect? What DBMS?

Comment: Hi WELCOME to SO, here you are not paying somthing to anyone if you have tried somthiong then show that. we'll resolve your problem. Otherwise google it.

Comment: i am using sql server 2008...

Comment: let me explain..there will b a form where we can enter the table name and fields and datatypes of it...and then when we click the create button..it should create a table of that particular name and fields..i need a stored procedure for that.

Comment: is it clear? can someone help me?

Comment: What is clear is that you you have not read the help pages with regard to how to use StackOverflow, in particular [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The site is specifically for exact technical questions, and your question is simply too broad without enough details.  It also feels like you're asking us to do the work for you

Comment: You should have provided more details in the question itself rather than in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the SP which will create a dynamic table for you. You need to pass tablename as 1st parameter and column names in 2nd parameter separated by tilde ` and the columnnames and datatypes separated by pipe |

```
--exec DynamicTables 'table1', 'firstname|varchar(1000)~lastname|varchar(1000)~phoneno|int'
Create proc DynamicTables
(
    @tablename varchar(100),
    @fieldsanddatatypes varchar(4000)
)

as

begin

declare @str varchar(4000);
set @str = 'create table ' + @tablename + ' ( ';

select @str = @str + substring(Splvalue, 1,CHARINDEX('|',Splvalue)-1) + ' ' + substring(Splvalue, CHARINDEX('|',Splvalue)+1,len(Splvalue)) + ','
from dbo.FnSplit(@fieldsanddatatypes,'~')

set @str = substring(@str,1,len(@str)-1) + ' )'

exec (@str)

end
```

In the SP, a function splits the column names and creates a dynamic script for creating table. The code for the function is below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit](@text varchar(max), @delimiter Nvarchar(20))  
RETURNS @Strings TABLE  
(       
 Splvalue Nvarchar(4000)     
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @index int   
SET @index = -1   
WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)   
BEGIN    
SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)    
IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)    
  BEGIN     
    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)  
      BREAK    
  END    
IF (@index >= 1)    
  BEGIN     
if (@index - 1) = 0  
 INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (Null)  
else     
 INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))     
SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))    
  END    
ELSE   
  SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))   
END  
RETURN  
END
```

Comment: no...i had errors while doing it.. but i got another solution and it is as follows..

Comment: You had said you needed multiple columns as well as datatypes in your table. The solution you provided will work only for one column with hardcode datatype whereas in my solution you can send that all through your code.

Comment: what errors are you getting? you need to send the columns to the SP in the same format as i have given in the example above, it wont give you any errors then

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sproc_BuildTable 
(
   @TableName NVARCHAR(128),
   @Column1Name NVARCHAR(32)
)

AS

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) 
BEGIN

SET @Query='CREATE TABLE '  + @TableName + '(' +@Column1Name + ' VARCHAR(200)'+ ')'
EXECUTE (@Query)

END
```

Comment: You had said you needed multiple columns as well as datatypes in your table. The solution you provided will work only for one column and that also with a hardcode datatype

Comment: yes rite.. now thats what m working on wthr i can make alter table like the same and keep adding columns..will that work?

Comment: in the method u said,how am i suppose to give inputs?

Comment: pass the column name parameters in the following format, "firstname|varchar(1000)~lastname|varchar(1000)~"

Comment: I tried am getting the error incorrect syntax new '|'.. if this works also if i want to add a column aftr creating table then i will definetly need an alter option too rite?

Comment: ya if you want to add column after creating, you need to write a separate SP for that. Can you show me what data are you passing in the @fieldsanddatatypes parameter?

Comment: yes, m giving the values as      name|varchar(1000)~phone|varchar(1000)